# 3D plotting from an m by n matrix

Tags: matrix, 3d, plot

I have a large file (over 2 million cells) and I need the value of each individual cell to be read as the z coordinate of a 3D plot and the original x,y coordinates of the cell to be the x and y coordinates in the graph. For example:

M =
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9

I need it to be read as (1,1,1) (2,1,2) (3,1,3)
                        (1,2,4) (2,2,5) (3,2,6)
                        (1,3,7) (2,3,8) (3,3,9)

And from there I need to create a 3D plot. Please help!

Comment: What language are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Pseudocode:

```
size = 3   # set this to the maximum value for x
x = 1
y = 1
z = readvalue()
while read succeeded
    plot(x, y, z)
    x = x + 1
    if x > size
        x = 1
        y = y + 1
    z = readvalue()
```